# Need help regarding sending SMS using java

Tags: java, email, smtp, sms

I want to send SMS using my java program. The scenario is that i have a server on which management program(written In java) is running. User can post their problems on the server. I want that when someone post their problem on server my java program generate an SMS to the user mobile number that your problem has been submitted.
I searched Google and found that you can use Java Mail API to send sms to user. I tried the program given on this [link](http://www.ehow.com/how_7896115_send-sms-using-jsp.html)

i used these parameters

```
......

public void msgSend() {

        String gmailUserName = "xxxx@gmail.com";
        String gmailPassword =  "xxxx";
        String smtpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String compression = "My Sms Compression information";
        String from = "Basit@smtp.gmail.com";
        String to = "03072525725@sms.smtp.gmail.com";
        String body = "Hi how r u";
        Transport myTransport = null;
        ...
        ...
```

After using this i received an email on my Gmail account with the
 following error

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> 03072525725@sms.smtp.gmail.com
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: DNS Error: Domain name not
>   found

I think that perhaps i didn't configure my Gmail account for mobile that's why i got this error. But i want to ask is it possible that i send sms using Java Mail API?

Comment: I think that the problem is that this DNS sms.smtp.gmail.com doesn't exist ! but I don't know what should I put excatly to make it work with SMS ...

Answer (score 4):

The error message shows you exactly the problem:

```
DNS Error: Domain name not found
```

There is no DNS entry for `sms.smtp.google.com`. It doesn't have anything to do with your settings. Google does not offer a public SMS gateway (sending SMS normally costs money).

You could try [Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/), for example.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use email to send messages via SMS using an [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways). It does require you to know the recipient phone number's carrier however.

For example:

Using the chart in the Wikipedia article in the link above, if the phone number is 7675431234 and the carrier is AT&T, then the email address to use would be `7675431234@txt.att.net`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer laz !
I didn't understand what do you mean by the recipient phone number's carrier can you give me an example please

Comment: If the phone number is 7675431234 and the carrier is AT&T, then the email address to use would be 7675431234@txt.att.net according to the chart in that Wikipedia article I linked to.