# Sending SMS from a pc to a mobile using java

Tags: java, email, smtp, sms

I have built an application which sends SMS messages via Java, but I am getting many exceptions during the application execution (see below):

```
package john;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SMTPSend {

    public SMTPSend() {
    }

    public void msgsend() {
      String username = "mygmailuserid@gmail.com";
      String password = "mygmailpassword";
      String smtphost = "smtp.gmail.com";
      String compression = "My SMS Compression Information";
      String from = "mygmailid@gmail.com";
      String to = "+91mymobilenumber@sms.gmail.com";
      String body = "Hello SMS World!";
      Transport myTransport = null;

try {
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
msg.setSubject(compression);
msg.setText(body);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());

 myTransport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
  myTransport.connect(smtphost, username, password);
  msg.saveChanges();
  myTransport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
  myTransport.close();
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
 SMTPSend smtpSend = new SMTPSend();
 smtpSend.msgsend();
}
} //
```

The application is running but in my mail box I have received the following:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

+91mymobilenumber@sms.gmail.com
```

How can I send an SMS using Java code/libraries?

Comment: Check that the firewall you are behind allows access to port 465 on smtp.gmail.com

Comment: i have turned off the windows firewall of my pc

Comment: Try using the port 587 for mail.smtp.port

Comment: Are you able to `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` at all? It doesn't work for me here. I think you're either using the wrong combination of hostname/port or your firewall/ISP has blocked that port.

Comment: i changed 465 to 587 but exceptions arised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make some modifications to the following variable:

```
String smtphost = "gmail.com";
```

Replace it with:

```
String smtphost = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Comment: ya thanks no error came but how can i receive the sms? i did not receive any sms to my mobile

Comment: just wait for a minute, it might depends on your operator.

Comment: please try this above code and tell me what modifications else is required

Comment: i found this in my mail box: Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

+91mymobilenumber@sms.gmail.com

Comment: `Technical details of permanent failure:
DNS Error: Domain name not found` That's the error when you use `+91mymobilenumber@sms.gmail.com` which means that `sms.gmail.com` is not a valid domain.

Comment: thanks but how can i send sms using java then? give me some idea

Comment: why you are using gmail for sending SMS ? you can try the otherway by attaching a GMS Modem into your computer system & firing AT commands for sending SMS by Java Code.

Comment: go to java2s.com & search for listport code & edit that code with AT Commands for sending message. for AT Commands again google it.

Answer (score 5):

Gmail does not provide a gateway for sending public SMS.

Sending SMS messages normally costs money.

Check this link out, it can prove to be helpful:

[SMS JAVA Sample Code](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22)

Here is a link to another question asked on SO regarding the same issue:

[i want to send sms to phone using java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8251037/1057230)